# Extending express.Request in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I can easily extend express.Request in typescript, e.g.:

```
interface MyRequest extends express.Request {
    userId: string;
}
```

However, if I write a middleware function that uses it, e.g.:

```
const myMiddlewareFn = (req: MyRequest, res: express.Response) => {
    req.userId; // <-- this works as a string
}
app.get('/user', myMiddlewareFn) // <-- this does NOT type-check because MyRequest is more narrow than express.Request.
```

I see a lot of discussions on how to extend express.Request. How can I do it in a way that will typecheck correctly in my route?

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
/**
 * @param allowedRoles see HasuraCustomClaims
 * @param handlerFn the final business logic
 * @returns an array of middleware, correctly typed for the handlerFn
 */
export function addApiAuthMiddleware(
    allowedRoles: string[],
    ...handlerFns: (
        | ((req: OTApiAuthorizedRequest, res: Response) => Promise<void>)
        | ((req: OTApiValidatedAndAuthorizedRequest<any>, res: Response) => Promise<void>)
    )[]
): express.RequestHandler[] {
    return [
        decodeIdToken,
        guardRequestHandler(createRoleAuthMiddleware(allowedRoles)),
        ...handlerFns.map((handlerFn) => guardRequestHandler(handlerFn)),
    ];
}

/**
 * This typecasting is a *little* jank.
 *
 * @param middlewareOrHandlerFn either api middleware or a final api handler function
 * @returns
 */
export function guardRequestHandler<T extends Request>(
    middlewareOrHandlerFn:
        | ((req: T, res: Response, next: express.NextFunction) => Promise<void>)
        | ((req: T, res: Response) => Promise<void>),
): express.RequestHandler {
    return (middlewareOrHandlerFn as unknown) as express.RequestHandler;
}

// this below type-checks
app.get('/user', ...addApiAuthMiddleware(['admin'], userHandlerFn));
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can change **app.get('/user', myMiddlewareFn)** to **app.get('/user', myMiddlewareFn as any)** or **app.get('/user',  myMiddlewareFn)** these are identical and both are **compile-time casts**. **Not runtime**.

Comment: **1.** `app.get('/user', myMiddlewareFn)` throws a type-error, no?
**2.** `app.get('/user', myMiddlewareFn as any)` this seems a bit scary to me, I know that it works, but the issue is that the developer can now accidentally screw up myMiddlewareFn (e.g. what if they now want to take in a next even when it doesn't exist!?!?) or they just screw up etc., the `any` will mask those mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Set your custom attributes are optional attributes.

```
interface MyRequest extends express.Request {
    userId?: string; // userId is optional
}
```

In your middleware or request handler, you always need to make sure that the `userId` is not undefined.

```
const myMiddlewareFn = (req: MyRequest, res: express.Response) => { // missing next function ?
    if (req.userId) {
        // do something with userId
        req.userId; // <-- this works as a string
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and satisfies the type checker, but in my view, isn't the main benefit that I get nice type-safe middleware without needing to do a null check?

e.g. imagine I use joi validation before my middleware. Some are required fields, others are not. In the case in which my Req is always a Partial<...> then it's not really capturing "required", right?

Comment: How to make sure that you use Joi validation before your middleware?

Comment: I can't! I guess what you're saying is that we *should* do a solution where, in order to type-check, I do *need* to wrap my controller with some type-guarding that does validation?